# unable to create Heroku postgresSql table

Tags: python, heroku-postgres

i am new to heroku and trying to connect to heroku db from python. I am running the following from
heroku console(heroku run)

```py
import psycopg2.extras
import psycopg2
from os import environ

URL = environ["DATABASE_URL"]

conn = psycopg2.connect(URL)

cur = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)

cur.execute(
    "CREATE TABLE files (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, FileName VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE NOT NULL, Content TEXT );")

conn.close()

print("TABLE CREATED")
```

but after this when i try to run any sql command , it just gives error

```
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "files" does not exist
```

**[i have no procfile]** 
i don't know what to do to make it work

Comment: There is no way you can run app on heroku without using `Procfile`

Comment: So how to do it using  a procfile.i don't want to create new table every time a dyno is assigned.

Comment: (btw i didn't needed a procfile because I want to run scripts only manually, when I needed them). Further can you tell how to make it work using a procfile

Comment: thats not how things work on heroku add `Procfile` and write `worker: python3 yourfilename.py` and turn on dyno when you dont want to run turn off dyno soo simple

Comment: Thanks, I will do that, but now what to add on a procfile to make the database work. It is creating a table, but on next dyno startup it is giving error that table does not exist.

Comment: You need to add `heroku-postgres` addon . When you will add this it will  setup database for you and you can access that database using url . Just define `URL = os.getenv("DATABASE_URL")`

Comment: I have done that, and able to create a table, but only until next dyno restart

Comment: That means your table are  created after every run make something such that if table exist   it will not make it again.;

Comment: No, read the question, it is showing <tablename> doesn't exist. And I have different python file for creating table which I am only running manually once , so pretty sure that not overwriting anything

Comment: In ` heroku postgres` the things dont deleted automatically it cause your script after every run delete the database . Why to run different file for creating file . Can you check whether after your table doesn't get deleted automatically at local filesytem?

Comment: I don't have postgres in my pc, can it be a reason

Comment: So please try in your pc system first and then host  anywhere  and stop extra .